# Does $\prod_{j=0}^{k}\frac{x-j}{y-j}$ have a special name?

Tags: combinatorics, terminology

I have been working on a combinatorial problem and the function describing a property of the population of $y$ objects where $x$ of them are a specific type. ($x$ and $y$ are always whole numbers and $x<y$)

I have ended up with is best represented in this form:

$f_n(x,y)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}{a_k\prod_{j=0}^{k}\frac {x-j}{y-j}}$

Because for the special case of an infinite population $y\to\infty$ the function becomes a simple polynomial of the population fraction, eg if $\hat{x}=\frac {x}{y}$

$\lim_{x,y\to\infty}\frac{x}{y}=\hat{x}$

$\lim_{x,y\to\infty}f_n(x,y)=g_n(\hat{x})=\sum_{i=0}^{n} {a_i}{\hat{x}}^n$

Obviously given the $a_i$ constants are the same for the infinite form based on the population fraction, $g_n(\hat{x})$, and the finite form $f_n(x,y)$ it makes sense to structure the finite form as above.

Is there a name for the k order product which is approximately a ratio to the power of k, but behaves differently with small numbers because when you exhaust the $x$ objects the product short-cuts to $0$ whereas the infinite case stays contributing

$\prod_{j=0}^{k}\frac{x-j}{y-j}\approx {\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)}^n$

Is there a special name for:

$\prod_{j=0}^{k}\frac{x-j}{y-j}$

Comment: Individually, the numerator and denominator are [falling factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials).

Comment: Yes, I spent quite a while before I found the rearrangement that gives the limit form for an infinite population in terms of the same polynomial constants... but I’m trying to describe the non-limit form of $\hat{x}^n$

Comment: “The n-th power of the population fraction” is ok in the text... but I’m really looking for a snappy name for the finite case

Comment: If you want to answer something like “the ratio of two falling factorials” I’d be happy to accept that... at least until someone comes along with something that is a special case name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can write
$$\prod_{j=0}^k\frac{x-j}{y-j}=\frac{\prod_{j=0}^kx-j}{\prod_{j=0}^ky-j}=\frac{(x)_{k+1}}{(y)_{k+1}}$$
where $(x)_n$ is called the ["falling factorial"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials). I don't know if there's a specific name for the ratio of same-order falling factorials (but I'm not an authority in the field).

It's perhaps worth noting that the ratio is equal to a ratio of binomial coefficients (simply divide numerator and denominator by $n!$):
$$\frac{(x)_n}{(y)_n}=\frac{\dbinom{x}{n}}{\dbinom{y}{n}}$$
Maybe this form has been given a name somewhere in the vast literature on those coefficients.